# Laravel + Vue JS : Prevent access to pages without permission

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have a little concern doing to my project since I am depending on localstorage. What if someone knows how to manipulate it and change something besides of auth token I putted the roles and permssion of user logged in to website at localstorage. Let say the someone changed the `['accounting']` to `['accountings']` then in my codes I did `if(userDetails.roles === 'accounting')` so they can now view  the other page that its not for them. I actually made it once for a try using navigation guard but It feels me really hassle to check every request at server-side if this user is for that roles or not. What is the best practice for this?

This is currently what I did

```
if(to.matched.some(record=>record.meta.checkRolePermission)){
    const obj = {
    allowOnlyFor : to.meta.allowOnlyThisRoles
    }
    axios({
        url: '/prod/api/checkuserrolespermission',
        method: 'post',
        data: obj,
        config: 'JSON'
    })
    .then(response=>{
        if(response.status == 200){
            if(response.data.result === 'allowed'){
                next();
            }else{
                next({
                    path:'/prod'
                });
            }
        }
    })
    .catch(response=>{
        next({
            path:'/prod'
        });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I actually made it once for a try using navigation guard but It feels
>   me really hassle to check every request at server-side if this user is
>   for that roles or not. What is the best practice for this?

You should always be checking a user's role for every request if it is accessing sensitive information. It's quite simple to do so using middleware like:

```
// CheckRole.php
public function handle($request, $next, $role)
{
    return auth()->check() && auth()->user()->hasRole($role) ? $next($request) : abort(403);
}

// kernel.php
protected $routeMiddleware = [
...
    'check-role': CheckRole::class
...
]

// routes/web.php
Route::get('accounting/sensitive-data', 'AccountingController@sensitiveData')->middleware('check-role:accountant');
```

Never trust your client to handle all your authorization/authentication. The server is your last line of defense, so to speak, so it should be as tightly secured as possible.

All that being said, it is certainly possible to restrict client side route access - assuming you're building an SPA. Use the vue-router navigation guards to check the role. Here's a good tutorial:

https://medium.com/@manojkumar_88220/role-based-authentication-using-vue-js-2-f54e18498019